# Changing a child span to a link which calls a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an **AJAX** function which populates a `div` with spans of data into a template. I would like to append these spans to links, which when clicked call a function.  With what I do have, it does seem an href link is getting added, but the text itself is still not clickable.

Here's the html from the IDE as well as from the developer tools in IE :

```
 <div id="subtotal_menu">
    </div>
```

[image: page view]
[image: Developer tools IE]
Here's what I have tried so far:

```
 var $menu = $('#subtotal_menu');
 $menu.empty();
 $('#checkTemplate').tmpl(data.d.Checks).appendTo($menu);
 $("#subtotal_menu").find("span").attr('href','myfunction()');
```

Also tried to create a separate function to operate on the DOM element:

```
    function createVendorInvoiceLinks() {
           var subTotalmenu = document.getElementById("#subtotal_menu").find("span");
           var aTag = document.createElement('a');
           aTag.setAttribute('href', "myfunction()");
           subTotalmenu.appendChild(aTag); 
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

```
var $menu = $('#subtotal_menu');
$menu.find("span").append('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>');
// append an anchor to the span inside #subtotal_menu
// set javascript:void(0) as href to avoid unwanted behaviour on click

$('#subtotal_menu').on('click', 'a',function(){
    alert('clicked');
    // do whatever myfunction() does
});
//set up a proper event handler and use event-delegation to cope with 
//dynamic added element from e.g. your mentioned ajax-request
```

When you want the whole span to be clickable just change the binding from the event handler from `a` to `span`. This way you don't event need to append an anchor.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5gqgs2kh/)**

---

**Reference**

[jQuery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Is there a way to make the text itself a link? Like instead of showing D0001 as plain text, can I make that into the link for the function call? Do I use replace with?

Comment: @Crumblenautjs no need for this. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5gqgs2kh/1/) example

Comment: How do I get it so when a user hovers over a specific line that it highlights? Right now setting #subtotal_menu:hover { background-color: grey} makes the whole thing go grey.  Thanks again!

Comment: I would say you should use `#subtotal_menu div:hover { background-color: grey}` for this. But hard to say without knowing the html-markup

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the `<a>` element to the span, you should do the opposite:

```
function createVendorInvoiceLinks() {
       var subTotalmenu = document.getElementById("#subtotal_menu").find("span");
       var aTag = document.createElement('a');
       aTag.setAttribute('href', "myfunction()");
       aTag.appendChild(subTotalmenu); 
       }
```

So you don't generate a `<a>` with no content.